# Determining Yes or No?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

After inputting a string [length 1-20], only containing the chars **y** for yes and **n** for no,
your program should output the result (y or n). Example input: `yynynynny` would output y.

The result is determined by combining the y's and n's in the following way:

- **y**es and **n**o equals **n**o
- **y**es and **y**es equals **y**es
- **n**o and **n**o equals **y**es

If the string contains more than 2 characters (likely...), the calculation would look the same. Examples:

- **y**es and **y**es and **n**o equals **n**o (because the no merges with the first yes to no. then there are no and yes left and the same thing happens again)
- **n**o and **n**o and **n**o equals **n**o (the first two no's merge to yes, then there are yes and no left, which emerge to no)

Example input with output:

- `yynynynynyyn` = n

Tip: have in mind that the order of the chars your program works off doesn't care. (for example you can read the input from back, or from behind, mix the letters, sort it, whatever. What counts is the correct ouptput) have fun!

Winning criteria:
this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in byte wins.

Comment: Congratulations on the first challenge with clear specification! (although it's unfortunate that some community members don't like "too trivial" challenges....)

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162116/xor-reduction-bools).

Comment: The boolean relationship defined is XNOR, sometimes called EQV in older BASICs. It is the inverse of XOR, and can be achieved as NOT(XOR...) if using boolean values directly; the additional complexity in this challenge is strictly from the requirement to deal with strings of 'yn' in both input and output.

Comment: Can we output an alternative pair? Say `1` for `y`, and `0` for `n`.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of characters ie `["y", "n", "n"]`

Comment: Can we take input as an alternative pair? Say `1` for `y`, and `0` for `n`.

Comment: @Adám Then this would be an exact duplicate of the linked challenge, I guess not :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No, XNOR vs XOR. But why the unnecessary complication of I/O formats here, when the much related challenge doesn't need it?

Comment: XNOR is just NOT XOR so this would be too closely related to be kept open.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It's only a duplicate if it's "`1` for `n`, `0` for `y`"...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder If the only thing keeping this question from being a duplicate is different characters for input format, how is it not already a dupe?

Comment: Why not close the old one as a dupe of the new one? The old one was poorly received, and I think this one is more interesting

Comment: @ConorO'Brien What's wrong with doing this? HNQ questions rarely "have the correct votes".

Comment: @ConorO'Brien [Some discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=44628760#44628760).

Comment: The output format makes this more interesting than the problem it's marked a duplicate of. That one is just sum of elements, reduce modulo 2. Many of those answers would not be optimal here.

Comment: Your first example doesn't make sense to me. How does the no merge with the *first* yes? Isn't evaluation left-to-right? Do you mean the two yeses merge, then the resulting yes merges with the no to make no?

Comment: Could we have a few more examples?

Comment: Why close this as a duplicate of a heavily downvoted challenge? I voted to leave this open in the review queue.

Comment: @davidconrad you're right, but as I said, the order doesn't matter

Comment: Since the duplicate of this challenge was heavily downvoted, I don't think it's very helpful to close this as a duplicate. If anything, the older challenge should be a duplicate of this one since [it's policy to leave the better challenge open](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8286/31716) I've reopened this challenge

Comment: Can we output truthy or falsy values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
§yn№Ｓn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCQ6kyT0lHwTm/FCjmmVdQWhJcApRP19DUUVDKU9LU1LT@/7@yMg8E8yr/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｓ   Input string
   № n  Count number of `n`s
§yn     Circularly index into string `yn`
        Implicitly print appropriate character
```

Comment: Explain how it works,  please?

Comment: @Malandy *Link is to verbose version of code.*

Comment: @Adám Actually I usually add one, however I had just dashed this off in a work break and forgotten to edit one in.

Answer (score 15):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

*Thanks to [@RickHithcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock) for pointing out a mistake, now corrected. Also, 2 bytes off thanks to [@StewieGriffin!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)*

```matlab
@(s)'yn'(mod(sum(s+1),2)+1)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1hTvTJPXSM3P0WjuDRXo1jbUFPHSBNI/k/TUK@szINCoBrN/wA)

#### Explanation

The ASCII code point of `'y'` is odd, and that of `'n'` is even. The code

1. adds `1` to each char in the input string to make `'y'` even and `'n'` odd;
2. computes the sum;
3. reduces the result to `1` if even, `2` if odd;
4. indexes (1-based) into the string `'yn'`.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but [this seems to function the same way in a few limited test cases](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1hTvTJPXSM3P0WjuDQXyNUx0tQ21PyfpqFeWZkHhUAVmv8B) for -4 bytes. It's probably wildly wrong because I don't know Octave!

Comment: @DomHastings Fails for yynynynny given in the OP, should return y, but returns n

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```javascript
s=>'ny'[s.split`n`.length&1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k49r1I9ulivuCAnsyQhL0EvJzUvvSRDzTD2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGep66pqaCvr5CHheaRCVUohJDArcWnHry8nCaVpkHAjAj/wMA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
y=>'yn'[n=1,~~eval(y.join`^`)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/S1k69Mk89Os/WUKeuLrUsMUejUi8rPzMvIS5BM/Z/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0np6eep56rKamgr6@Qh4XFtlKmGwlVlkCmvHrzsvDb3hlHhQiWfMfAA)

Comment: 31: `s=>'yn'[s.match(/n/g).length&1]` :P

Comment: @ASCII-only This would fail on strings that do not contain at least one `n`.

Comment: Oh, it would. Oops >_>

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/),  <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```hs
f a=cycle"yn"!!sum[1|'n'<-a]
```

Indexes the count of n's into the infinite list "ynynynyn…".
Previous approach (33 bytes) was folding pairs of different elements to n, otherwise y:

```hs
f=foldl1(\a b->last$'y':['n'|a/=b])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h0Ta5MjknVakyT0lRsbg0N9qwRj1P3UY3MfZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoJSZWUeFAKV//@XnJaTmF78Xze5oAAA)

Comment: Your previous approach can be done in 30 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0KxsqbC1rbSVr1SvcbQzsBWPU@dK802LT8npchQQ1Hzf25iZp5tQVFmXolKmlJeZWVlXmWe0n8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ċ”nị⁾ny
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96OGuXkPd3c/atyXB@T/V8/LUwcA)

**ċ**ount number of **”n**, **ị**ndex into the string **⁾ny**. (with modulo 2)

---

```
ċḢịɗ⁾ny
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I98Mdix7u7j45/VHjvjygwH/1vDx1AA)

{**ċ**ount number of, take the **Ḣ**ead, then **ị**ndex into} string **⁾ny**.

---

```
OCSị⁾ny
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/fOfjh7u5HjfvygJz/6nl56gA)

Similar to the Octave answer above. Calculate **O**rd value, take the **C**omplement (for each ord value *x* calculate *1-x*), **S**um, then **ị**ndex into string **⁾ny**.

Comment: It was my bogus solution confusing me!

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
'ny'[1+=/'y'=⍞]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9Ii@/6L96XqV6tKG2rb56pbrto955sSCZ/wpgAFLAVVmZB4WVeQA)

Note: TIO defaults to `⎕IO = 1`. If run with `⎕IO←0`,

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
'ny'[=/'y'=⍞]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9Ii@/6L96XqV6tK2@eqW67aPeebEg8f@P@qZ6@j9qm2DApQAGIIVclZV5UFiZBwA)

This is the XNOR function (sometimes called EQV, especially in old BASICs.

#### Decomposition/Analysis:

```apl
             ⍞  - Accept string input  
         'y'=   - Compare it to the letter `y`. This "converts" the input 
                  string into a vector of 1s and 0s where the 1s correspond 
                  to 'y' and the 0s to 'n'.  
       =/       - XNOR/EQV/equality reduction - converts the vector into a 
                  single boolean value by evaluating e.g., 1 xnor 0 xnor 0 
                  xnor 1 ...  
     1+         - adds one for subscripting in ⎕IO = 1 environment. In 
                  ⎕IO = 0, should be omitted (save 2 bytes)  
    [         ] - subscript indicator - the expression, which should be 
                  either a 1 or 2 (0 or 1 in `⎕IO = 0`), is now going to be 
                  interpreted as a subscript of...  
'ny'            - The string of possible results - a 0/1 is 'n', a 1/2 is 'y'
```

Comment: While XOR ignores 0s and flips on 1s, XNOR ignores 1s and flips on 0s, “initially” being at 1 instead of 0 like XOR.

Comment: @FrownyFrog - I suppose you could look at it that way... or you could look at it as being a check to see if both of its input values are the same.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda s:'yn'[s.count('n')%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSr0yTz26WC85vzSvREM9T11T1Sj2f0FRJpCXpqFUWZkHhZV5Spqa/wE)

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
@"yn"l@\n
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%22yn%22l%40%5Cn&input=%22yynynynynyyn%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
@"yn"l@\n
     l@\nQ   Get the length of the intersection of the (implicit) input and "n".
@"yn"        Modular index into "yn".
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
"yn"gUèn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X6kyTyk99PCKPBCzMg8KgYIA)

### Explanation:

```
"yn"gUèn
"yn"       String literal - "yn"
    g      Return the char at index:   
      è      Number of matches where:
       n       "n" is found in
     U         Input
```

Japt uses index-wrapping, so if `Uèn` returns `2`, it will return `y` when getting the char from `"yn"`.

Comment: Identical to what I had.

Answer (score 6):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 39

```
?dsiZdsl[[]r1-d0<m]dsmxklixzll-2%B*C1+P
```

Input string is read from STDIN and should be in the form `[yynynynynyyn]`.

dc is not known for its string handling, but we have just enough here to get this to work.  The approach here is to count the `n`s, and output `y` if even or `n` if odd.  This is done by executing the input string as a macro.  `dc` will output `'y' (0171) unimplemented` errors for all the `y`s and attempt to pop strings and print them for all the `n`s.  So first we make sure we have plenty (total input string length) of empty strings `[]` on the stack to pop.  Then we execute the input string and see how many `[]` are left on the stack.  The original string length is subtracted from this to give the (-ve) total number of `n`s.  The rest is arithmetic to do mod 2 and have the output come out right as ASCII `y` or `n`.

```
?dsi                                    # Read input string, duplicate, store in register i
    Zdsl                                # Get input length, duplicate, store in register l
        [         ]                     # define macro to:
         []                             #   push empty string
           r                            #   swap empty string and remaining length 
            1-                          #   subtract 1 from length
              d0                        #   duplicate and compare with 0
                <m                      #   if >0 recursively call this macro again
                   dsmx                 # duplicate macro, store in register m and execute
                       k                # discard left-over 0
                        lix             # load input string and execute as macro
                           z            # get stack length
                            ll-         # load string length and subract
                               2%       # mod 2 (result is -ve because difference is -ve)
                                 B*     # multiply by 11 ('y' - 'n')
                                   C1+  # add 121 ('y')
                                      P # print result as ASCII char
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@pTgzKqU4Jzo6tshQN8XAJjc2pTi3Ijsns6IqJ0fXSNVJy9lQO@D//@jKyjworMyLBQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{<y n>[.comb('n')%2]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwEETv@xVzsMaAeOjBi5ofKSXUmEJBVzFYCOK3p4mllIHl7TAzi13HOmzO4l1XpiGaPHIzDxZd2FsPVrfKzFNfCBbycr0fwW09hpdbxodHgUxDYifAxTfTJQQ6BVEibRSZlnQQVfmv8JxXtDHtPSexT8ynEQ9/iU/kfywqmqqh8AE)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  # index into the list ('y', 'n')
  <y n>[

    .comb('n') # get every instance of 'n' (implicit method call on $_)
    % 2        # turn it into a count and get the modulus

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
{&'ny'@=/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT6FaTT2vUt3BVv9/anJGvkKagnqeOheMWYlg5lUic/KQOJUovDyQwv8A)

Comment: Very clever usage of reduction!

Comment: Really nice solution(s)!

Comment: Would you please provide a decomposition of the/both solutions (as I did with my APL solution)? (Incidentally, you should really post the APL solution as a separate solution from the J solution, even if the algorithm is the same.)

Comment: `{&'ny'@=/` saves a byte.

Comment: @algorithmshark ohhh thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 35 bytes

A decider for a regular language! I can do that.

```java
s->s.matches("y*(ny*ny*)*")?'y':'n'
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XVDBboMwDD3DV1iRKgii@YB26w6Vdtupx2kHj4Y2LBhEQqto6rezpMBaETlKnv1sP7vCC66bVlJ1/Bna/lurAgqNxsAHKoLfOJqcxqL1T6kINVQ@S/RWaVH2VFjVkHifPi8H2yk65bA/Y4eFld0OkMxVdvA6mPXOiBptcZYmZS5LyWXeeMb4W@KSTULJEG3jZdNLo45Qez3pWPzzC7A7GR7kRWXTweQH3KORsAGSV/inBlLEaDyO5XfowiE3w0WIwn0OPeMQfrApoDlzYj4qEbllS@bBbZQeHZyxshZNb0Xr1Vo9Tyj8VH5PKVsZP86qYPk4Wz7tUmDbapfefZzzbagZe7sNfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O‘Sị⁾ny
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//UcOM4Ie7ux817ssDcv9XVuaBYF4lAA)**

Comment: `Ẉ` can be used instead of `L€`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```r
"if"(sum(1+utf8ToInt(scan(,"")))%%2,"n","y")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XykzTUmjuDRXw1C7tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR0lJU1NTVdVIRylPSUepUknzf15eJRDkVeb9BwA)

Down 2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe and ngm. Port of the Octave answer by Luis Mendo.

Comment: It's easiest to get inspired by the Octave answer; while Octave has the advantage that strings are converted to their code points more easily, I think you can port the approach there for a couple bytes down.

Comment: `sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,""))%%2)%%2` saves one byte.

Comment: @ngm @Giuseppe sadly `n` is even so have to add+1 first..

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 9 bytes

Oliver beat me to the shortest solution so here are a couple that are just a byte longer.

```
B*aUèÍu¹d
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QiphVejNdblk&input=Inl5bnlueW55bnl5biI=)

```
#ndB*UèÍv
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I25kQipV6M12&input=Inl5bnlueW55bnl5biI=)

---

### Explanations

```
              :Implicit input of string U
B             :11
 *            :Mutiplied by
  a           :  The absolute difference of 11 and
   UèÍ        :    The count of "n" in U
      u       :    Mod 2
       ¹d     :Get the character at that codepoint
```

```
              :Implicit input of string U
#n            :110
   B*         :Add 11 multiplied by
        v     :  The parity of
     UèÍ      :    The count of "n" in U
  d           :Get the character at that codepoint
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```perl
s/y|ny*n//g;s;^$;y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79Yv7Imr1IrT18/3brYOk7FuvL//8rKvLy8Si4QmVeZB@T9yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA)

Similar to the [Retina solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165222/78123).

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 24 bytes

```
/ny/n//nn/y//yy/y//yn/n/<input>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz@vUj9PXz8vT79SX7@yEkzmAUX@/wcA)

I believe this is the shortest possible /// program, as making a one character substitution either is useless (if you insert something in its place) or prevents it from being an output (if you insert nothing). However, since the program must deal with the two character cases, this should be minimal.

First removes all `y`s right of an `n`. Then replaces double `n`s with `y`s, taking advantage of LTR substitution. At this stage there are many `y`s followed by at most one `n`; we deduplicate the `y`s and if there is an `n` use it to mop the last `y` up.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
Qs'ny'w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7BYPa9SvVzz/38gnQdG6gA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo! I previously used the explicit modulus command to get the index into the range `1,2`.

#### Explanation

This uses the fact that MATL have modular indexing, which means that the 1st, 3rd, 5th ... element of the string `ny` are the same (`n`). So are the 2nd, 4th, 6th ... element of the string (`y`).

```
Q          % Grab input implicitly, and increment each ASCII-value by 1
           % This makes 'n' odd, and 'y' even
 s         % Take the sum of all elements
  'ny'     % Push the string `ny`
      w    % Swap the stack to facilitate the indexing
       )   % Take the n'th element of 'yn' and output it.
```

Comment: `'yn'3)` gives `y`...? Now that's clever design Luis =) Thanks for the tips! :)

Comment: It was [Dennis' suggestion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75841/parity-of-a-permutation/75853#comment184427_75853) :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:'yn'[int(s,35)%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSr0yTz06M69Eo1jH2FRT1Sj2f0ERkKuQpgGS0VSwtVVQz1PnQghWQgUrkQTz8rAIVmLVn5eH3dQ8EMyrxG4OFCIZ@B8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 11 bytes

```
y

nn

^$
y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v5KLKy@PiytOhasSyKnMg8LKPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>20</s> 11 bytes

```
q~'ne="yn"=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOPS/VVqkyT8n2/3@lyso8KAQKAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
'n¢„ynsè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPe/QokcN8yrzig@v@P@/sjIPCivzAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 143 bytes

```java
a->{char[] u=a.toCharArray();if(u.length==1)return u[0];else{char b=(u[0]==u[1])?'y':'n',i=2;for(;i<u.length;b=(b==u[i++])?'y':'n');return b;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY@xbsIwEIZ3nuLEEluUqHSscauqc5WBMcpwCQ6YhkvknJGsKM@empKqI@imO3367/9OeMF12xk67b@nqsG@hy@0NCwALLFxNVYGsqE6ogMnduwsHQClGiPQM7KtIIPMc@cZNEy4fvtl8wK8xpTbz7h8OIdBSGVr4dPG0IGPWm@kM@wdgc@fC2Wa3tyelFpcL1r7fFPI9yQkrwklT1a/qLp1QtntX4aKaHnl7Gr1T0o155ZqHCcVa3a@bGLNue2ltXs4R8VZJi9QDotd6Nmc09Zz2sUrNyRuUqkTyxCIwlJKdRebJ9Aj9H3mkZgbE1V/AA)

And if we take the input as a list:

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 118 bytes

```java
u->{if(u.length==1)return u[0];else{char b=(u[0]==u[1])?'y':'n',i=2;for(;i<u.length;b=(b==u[i++])?'y':'n');return b;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZAxa8MwEIX3/IojiyXSmKZjVTWEzsVDRuNBduREqXMy8ikgjH@7KxOXLoVibjg43nv33V3VXW1tq/F6@hqrRnUdfCqD/QrAIGlXq0pD1lcX5cCxqeUFeC6GKOhIkakgg8xT6wkkjH773pua@bTReKaLlDvuNHmH4PPnQuim04@sUrJpIqXPdwXfJyF5TTB5MvJF1NYxYd5@MkSUlpPObDa/Si7m3FIMwygiTevLJtLMUHdrTnCLl7AjOYPnvFC8Xx1DR/qWWk9pG6fUIHuwp46tQ0AM65TsRwQ8OKcC45yLf01zBVzuXepYvuIvR3zYNw)

#### Explanation:

(input as string)

```java
char[] u=a.toCharArray();  //turn string into char array
if(u.length==1){    
    return u[0];      //if single letter, return it
}else{
    char b=(u[0]==u[1])?'y':'n';     //first two XNOR
    for(char i=2;i<u.length;b=(b==u[i++])?'y':'n');   //XNOR each remaining character
return b;    //return final result
}
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis at your ternary-ifs (-4 bytes), you can remove the space at `char[]u` (-1 byte); and `if(u.length==1)` can be `if(u.length<2)` (-1 byte). There is probably more to golf, but I don't really have the time right now. :)

Answer (score 2):

### F#, <s>54</s> 50 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni).

```
let c=Seq.reduce(fun a x->if a=x then 'y'else 'n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsIwFEX3fsWlUGKHiB9gs7kLjupQ4osG6qumqSTgvz/TLnKGe5dz3KTtGEhkoAjbnei9DXSbLW3czOiRtPEOfZcQH8RQWdEwERSrVs77A8eQj6PnaK7VUnj2vljh/kFXYYn5SAFrK0Eb2DJfg1coimPUzXSJja2R2tWqsBPJWZgls3Aunxf@r5D5Bw)

`Seq.reduce` applies a function with an accumulator (`a`)  to each element (`x`) in the string. For the first call, `a` is the first element in the string and `x` is the second element.

Comment: It looks like the space after `'y'` can be removed.

Comment: `i` can also be removed by Eta-conversion: `let c=Seq.reduce(fun a x->if a=x then 'y'else 'n')`. And as our general rules allow anonymous functions, you can drop the `let c=` part as well.

Comment: I like the Eta-conversion! But can you link to that rule about anonymous functions please? It seems a little strange not to have the function definition in the submitted code, even for anonymous functions.

Comment: The meta consensus is here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/56433

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->s{"yn"[s.count(?n)%2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BCoMwDIbvPkUIFBQ6DzsO6h6k9OC0MkGi2BZW5p69yzadSCDhz/cnIXO4xdSpdKrcEyOhdmUzBvL5lQpxNq@kQWNECZyMzIAVfRRtKjLcGW@QO6N4UHRwRlpjm8lMaevmDu0IS09T8BLsY7KNt@3CI7N1YfCgoNNfarjHxQHmwhUgHKiKM4IAvXnVfwNcAafaMb4AdnU/8BPrkZ/ZZJba9AY)

A lambda taking a string and returning a string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-z`, 24 bytes

```
B}Zvv~vedSD~t
 `'bc af*g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/36k2qqysriw1JdilroRLIUE9KVkhMU0r/f//yso8KKzM@69bBQA)

#### Explanation

This prints `'h'`, which is `'n' & 'y'`:

```
        d    
       f*g
```

This converts the `'h'` to either an `'n'` or a `'y'`, according to whether the top-left wire is powered:

```
   vv~ve     
   bc a
```

This is the xor counter, it powers the part described above as necessary:

```
B}Z          
 `'
```

Finally, this causes the program to only print the last output and terminate when the input is exhausted (the `-z` flag adds a null terminator for this purpose):

```
         SD~t
```

Try replacing the `S` with a space to see the running result (the first `'y'` is extraneous, the second char matches the first input, and the third is the result of the first nontrivial calculation).

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

Been a while since I played with Cubix, so ...

```
i;iwW-?;o@..!'yv.n'|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z/TOrM8XNfeOt9BT09RvbJML0@95v//yso8KKzMAwA)

Fairly naive implementation that steps through the string and compares the character against current result.

[Interactive Demo](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIGkgOwogICAgaSB3ClcgLSA/IDsgbyBAIC4gLgohICcgeSB2IC4gbiAnIHwKICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=eXlueW55bnlueXlu&speed=20)

This unwraps onto the cube as follows

```
    i ;
    i w
W - ? ; o @ . .
! ' y v . n ' |
    . .
    . .
```

- `W` shift ip left
- `i` get the initial character
- `i?` get character and test for EOI (-1), also start of the loop

  - if EOI `;o@` remove TOS, output TOS as character and exit.
- else `-W!` subtract, shift ip left, test for truthy

  - if truthy `'n` push character n to TOS
  - if falsey `|!'y` reflect, test and push character y to TOS
- `v'.;w` redirect around the cube pushing and  removing a . character and shifting right back into the loop

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 50 Bytes

```
def?(b:String)=b.reduce((r,l)=>if(r==l)'y'else'n')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>52</strike> 50 bytes

Thanks to @Neil for the suggestions.

I borrowed the solution of counting `n`s, but instead of keeping a count, I just flip between the initial state and its inverse on an `n`.

```c
i;f(char*a){for(i=*a;*++a;i^=*a&1?0:23);return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFET3PcWnoiRpFaM7o/UgohB@m/aDphLTQig9e0xFZvOYNwxuW8S4IovPoW7g/PE19buuiqQMw047oflkesfoIrQSRaEVPRJu5HV/Ohy5co0fnAVScyTr4aXJsgW0a7FcDkCIxCOHKQMgwxZRSQ5vl2aG5WvMy1873uSdc5XNMYZg/wn2Cw)

Comment: `*a&1?0:23` saves a byte and `return i` saves another.

Comment: Suggest `i;f(char*a){for(i=*a;*++a;i^=*a&1?:23);a=i;}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 13 bytes

```
~k!aj@,+n'*b!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/vy5bMTHLQUc7T10rSfH//8rKPBDMqwQA)

Basically inverts a 0 for every `n` in the input, and once more for good measure, then outputs `y` for `1` and `n` for `0`

```
~     Get inputted character
 k!   Invert the current value 110 (n) or 121 (y) + 1 times
   aj Jump past the rest of the code
~     Get input again. If no more input, reverse direction
            ! Invert the value once again
       +n'*b  Convert 0/1 to n/y
     @,       Output letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <strike>39</strike>37 Bytes

```
s=>[...s].reduce((x,y)=>x==y?'y':'n')
```

Simple reduce function after splitting the input string.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your code assumes the input is in the variable `s`, which is [not a valid input method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/59183) here. You may instead make your answer a lambda function taking the input as an argument by prepending `s=>` to your answer for 42 bytes.

Comment: golfing suggestion: replace `s.split('')` with `[...s]` for 37 bytes: `s=>[...s].reduce((x,y)=>x==y?'y':'n')`

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
foldr1\a b|a==b='y'='n'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcexCsJADADQ3a@4LZOCH5CtS6GD4KgO6bUnB0lOrnEI@O1GpLzpZV5JQ9ry5jUJVY0qr9YtDWR0mupmh4Kl8dLPd0rzhxBnBAcEhbgadcOSbuCuf@rwiG8uTM8tjuMUgytJzXsuTFZalx8)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes using [lambda guards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154073/42682): `foldr1\a b|a==b='y'='n'`. (By the way, unfortunately usually imports are part of the bytecode.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), 32 Bytes

```
"yn"[s.filter{it=='n'}.length%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoMwFEVn8xUPoaiLlI6lKfgNHcUhg6ah6U1JXoWH@O2xKXc4HA7cV2DvkJcv6G0cWhNtutIQo5Hbg6ODvXe0qWo1nhJpKn08T6p4IJ1rQT2mfnGe57g51rpBs/d@huXn6TLl6vM7YY82dGrPAgGyFPwnOAA)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <strike>77</strike> 70 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUCjSrU5Mz8oGMaMNYTfs0jeKSopIiIFcnurLS1q5SpzLP1i5PJ68STALZlbGamlYqBda1/9M0lCor86CwMk9J01pBXz@1oiA1uSQ1RcGPC2SughKXkjUXWCVQSR6IBKlTQFYZiU1lHkQZqkq//wA)

**Code, recursive function**

```
function f($p){echo($p[1])?f(strtr($p,[yy=>y,yn=>n,ny=>n,nn=>y])):$p;}
```

**Explanation**

Why use `strtr` with a replace array like `[yy=>y,yn=>n,ny=>n,nn=>y]`, as the string the function takes can be shown like (example with test case `"yynynynynyyn"`)

```
  (y and y) and (n and y) and (n and y) and (n and y) and (n and y) and (y and n)
```

What does the function do?

```
  function f($p){
      echo($p[1])
           //The function will replace yy yn ny nn while strlen>1
           ?f(strtr($p,[yy=>y,yn=>n,ny=>n,nn=>y]))
           //Length greater than one, apply strtr
           :$p;
           //ok, just one letter left, "echo" it
     }
```

**With a loop, 83 Bytes**

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoAgFET3nqKFiwQ3rU07SLSIkAzi9zEphujsJhUDw7x5HDi3HQcWcozzYQH6AzKic5@sJNvXm@oMy@rrPcXVUy1ZuUZdxZYjxcK6B6yDBllHmvB22RiUuf0UNskm5wc)

Simulates "run as pipe"

**Code**

```
<?php $p=$argv; while(strlen($p)>1){$p=strtr($p,[yy=>y,yn=>n,ny=>n,nn=>y]);}echo$p;
```

**Explanation**

It does the exact same thing as the recursive function

```
$p=$argv; //Accepting value from the script variable
while(strlen($p)>1){ //the loop ends when string length is one
   $p=strtr($p,[yy=>y,yn=>n,ny=>n,nn=>y]); //replace
}
echo$p; //echo the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 44 bytes

```
(prompt()+"n").match(/n/gi).length%2?"y":"n"
```

Try it out on developer console.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
!"ny"#'n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X1Epr1JJWT3v////SpWVeVBYmacEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Å8Dq↨W<
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8f38447117573c&i=ynnyyyynnyn&a=1&m=2)

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you can use modular indexing to [get to 7](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8f38447117573c&i=ynnyyyynnyn&a=1&m=2).

Comment: @recursive what is modular indexing?

Comment: When you use `@` to get an element from an array, it "wraps around".  So you can use `@` to get an element from a 2-length array, and even indices return the first element, and odd ones return the last.  Basically `|e` (which determines parity of a number) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

Not the shortest but anyway

```
f[s_]:=Times@@StringCases[s,a={"y"->1,"n"->-1}]/.Reverse/@a
```

Call if `s` is your string of `y` and `n` (included between ".."), call `f[s]`.

All it does is to replace `y` by 1 and `n` by -1, then multiply them and replace the numbers back to strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
'n'/,2%'ny'1/=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz1PXV/HSFU9r1LdUN/2///Kyry8yjwgCQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>48</s> 43 bytes

```powershell
"$args"|% t*y|%{$z=$z-xor$_-eq'n'};'yn'[$z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fSSWxKL1YqUZVoUSrska1WqXKVqVKtyK/SCVeN7VQPU@91lq9Mk89WqUq9v///@qVlXlQCBQEAA)

Not the best method. Split into char array, use `-xor`, invert it implicitly at the end with the array lookup to get back a char.

Comment: Save 5 bytes by using `"yn"` instead of `('y','n')`.

Comment: Also, you need to compare against `'n'` and not `'y'` - you don't see this in your demo because there are equal numbers of each letter.

Comment: @Neil wow I can't believe I didn't use `'yn'`, I'm crazy rusty. I originally was comparing with `'n'` and now I can't remember why I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 91 bytes

```
package main;import ."strings";type s=string;func f(S s)(s){return s("yn"[Count(S,"n")%2])}
```

105 bytes if `;func main(){}` is added; unsure of Gode Golf golang norms.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 40 bytes

```clj
(if(even?(count(filter #(= %\n)s)))\y\n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcwxCoAwDEbhq4SKkAweQTyIOmkKlfJX2irk9NVBkLd809tiOq6sjXf1INMypDwg0VzWxsGz3oqJt3Shsg@xaqaOR@oXSBGRxV404TMH1Aji/@DM8GVwIu0B)

Answer (score 1):

[C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/)   **42 bytes**

```
g(char*a){return*a?"yn"[(g(a+1)^*a)&1]:1;}
```

[Try in online!](https://ideone.com/niIALu)

Solution is simply based on XNOR operation.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```
f=a=>(a.split("").map(b=>(b=="y")?1:-1).reduce((b,c)=>b*c)==1)?"y":"n";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 56 bytes

```
[H,H]-121.
[_,_]-110.
[A]-A.
[A,B|T]-S:-[A,B]-C,[C|T]-S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P9pDxyNW19DIUI8rOl4nHsg0NAAyHWN1HUGUjlNNSKxusJUuiBmr66wT7QwW0Ptvr6uQUFmZB4WVeQm6wToK5UWZJalpGkqqeUo6CtHBsZp6/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 52 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(s)(reduce(lambda(a b)(if(eq a b)#\y #\n))s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYq7CsAgDAD3fkXQJfknF18BwQY1dfDrbQsttxzHxVq0bdR8deCN1Z8heVTCkdOM@Q8eAmFhzB1etW6BdUKkRJsObKNIBOQp0dcKDGYt@VhinukG)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
'n¢„ynè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPe/QokcN8yrzDq/4/7@yMg8KK/MA)

```
'n¢„ynè  # full program
      è  # character in...
         # (implicit) commutative indèx...
   „yn   # literal...
      è  # at 0-based index...
         # (implicit) commutative, modular indèx...
  ¢      # number of...
'n       # literal...
  ¢      # s in...
         # implicit input
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'nc`ynsi
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSduYyU2MHluc2kmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD15eW55bnlueW55eW4mZmxhZ3M9)

Same as all the other answers

```
'nc`ynsi  # Implicit input
'nc       # Count of "n"s
      si  # modularly indexed
   `yn    # into the string "yn"
          # Implicit output
```