# Pairs at every distance

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Given a list \$X\$ of 2 or more integers, output whether, for all \$n\$ such that \$0 \leq n < length(X)-2\$, there exists a pair of equal integers in \$X\$ separated by exactly \$n\$ elements.

In other words: output whether, for all overlapping slices/windows of the input, there exists at least one slice/window of each length wherein the head of the slice/window equals the tail.

For example: `[1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]` will return truthy, because

```
[1, x, x, x, x, x, x, 1]
These 1s are separated by 6 elements, the most possible in an 8 element list,

[x, 1, x, x, x, x, x, 1]
These 1s are separated by 5 elements,

[1, x, x, x, x, 1, x, x]
These 1s are separated by 4 elements,

[x, 1, x, x, x, 1, x, x]
These 1s are separated by 3 elements,

[x, x, x, 2, x, x, 2, x]
These 2s are separated by 2 elements,

[x, x, 3, x, 3, 1, x, 1]
These 3s are separated by 1 element (as are the 1s, but either pair is sufficient),

[1, 1, x, x, x, x, x, x]
And these 1s are separated by 0 elements, the least possible.
```

But `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]` will return falsy, as there is no pair of equal elements separated by exactly one element. That is, there is no length 3 slice/window with a head equal to it's tail. See all length 3 slices/windows below:

```
[1, 1, 2]
   [1, 2, 2]
      [2, 2, 1]
         [2, 1, 1]
```

Standard I/O applies, input does not have to allow negatives, or input can be a string of characters, etc.

Anything reasonable as long as you're not cheating :)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Examples

Truthy

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 7, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Falsy

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: _input does not have to allow negatives_ -> May the input contain 0's?

Comment: @Arnauld "etc", only if you want. EDIT: to elaborate; this isn't a challenge about integers so much as it's a challenge about matching pairs in a list. you can use church numerals for all I care :P

Comment: It seems like this problem is also interesting from the perspective of fastest code/algorithm. The best algorithm I could think of is \$ O(n \sqrt{n \log(n)}) \$

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't understand your edit. I think it's wrong, as it seems to imply `1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1` would return falsy, as `2 3 1 2` and `1 3 2 3 1` dont have the same head/tail (`2` vs `1`). I also don't see what's gained by using `|X|` in place of `length(X)`. I'm reverting it for now. EDIT: i see that my original wording also had that mistake. This should be a tad better. Feel free to reword this version, but I still don't agree with using absolute value bars for length. Seems like a barrier for entry.

Comment: The pre-existing wording made no sense at all.  It used the term "pair" to refer to nothing at all.  It is really that there are `n` pairs of one integer.

Comment: I also don't get why you want to use code formatting for math.

Comment: @WheatWizard the code formatting part is because i havent figured out how to use mathjax yet :P feel free to fix that lol.

Comment: @WheatWizard as for the pairs: the "pair" of integers is referring to the fact that there is an integer A, B integers, and then the integer A again. Those two A's are a pair.

Comment: The existing wording was fixed imo but if you take a look at the original wording you will see that that was not the case.

Comment: @WheatWizard yeah i definitely boned up a bit myself, but working from this version would probably be better. At least the window description is right, lol, i think thanks to lyxal for coming up with that in chat

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

Uses inverted boolean output.

```
IÐƤÄPẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z8IRjSw63BDzcteP/4fZHTWuA6P//6GiuaEMdBcNYHQgNZRrrKACROZAE8Yx0FIzAciAGVADKgwoYgtXDSSTjjMGKjGEakC1CQlCZWB2Ic2BmImmAGGICdRzCPoQAVAzFOahiCDfDPITDOWAncMXGAgA)

```
 ÐƤ     # Map over each suffix:
I       #   Increments (differences between adjacent elements)
   Ä    # For each list, get cumulative sums
    PẸ  # Is there a zero in each column?
```

This is basically: *Is there a zero on each diagonal of the subtraction table?*. The naive implementation would be:

```
_þ`ŒDP€Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@8L6Eo5NcAh41rXm4a8f/w@1ABhD9/x8dzRVtqKNgGKsDoaFMYx0FIDIHkiCekY6CEVgOxIAKQHlQAUOwejiJZJwxWJExTAOyRUgIKhOrA3EOzEwkDRBDTKCOQ9iHEICKoTgHVQzhZpiHcDgH7ASu2FgA)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>a.every((_,d)=>a.some(v=>a[d++]==v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RL7UstahSQyNeJ0UTxC3Oz03VKAOyolO0tWNtbcs0Nf8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2uoR4cUlZZkVMaqa3Ihi6dpRBvqKBjGamIVxi5jrKMAROZAEoukkY6CEVgniIFdHiqJXd4QbDicxO0yY7ARxjDj8HgBCcEUoqhUj8mLdkvMKcYRODhcidtOiLNMsIccwn845aFK8AUOXiWI8IXFBXGBA/XrfwA)

Or **38 bytes** with an inverted output, assuming the input list does not contain any 0:

```javascript
a=>a.some((_,d)=>a.every(v=>a[d++]^v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5Rrzg/N1VDI14nRRPESy1LLarUKAMyo1O0tWPjyjQ1/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6hHhxSVlmRUxqprciGLp2lEG@ooGMZqYhXGLmOsowBE5kASi6SRjoIRWCeIgV0eKold3hBsOJzE7TJjsBHGMOPweAEJwRSiqFSPyYt2S8wpxhE4OFyJ206Is0ywhxzCfzjloUrwBQ5eJYjwhcUFcYED9et/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // given an array a[] of N entries
  a.every((_, d) => // for each distance d = 0 to N - 1:
    a.some(v =>     //   is there some value v at position i (implied) ...
      a[d++] == v   //     ... such that a[i + d] is equal to v?
                    //     (we increment d instead of storing i explicitly)
    )               //   end of some()
  )                 // end of every()
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
żƛ?l'ṪǏ⁼;;A
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLFvMabP2wn4bmqx4/igbw7O0EiLCIiLCJbMSwgMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV0iXQ==)

*-1 thanks to EmanresuA but also -10 rep thanks to EmanresuA so now I have to edit the post so the upvote can be returned*

### Explained

```
żƛ?l'ṪǏ⁼;;A
żƛ           # For every number n in the range [0, len(input)]
  ?l         #   Overlapping windows of length n of the input
    'ṪǏ⁼;    #   Get all sublists where the list is the same after appending the head of the list to the list with the tail chopped off. That is, `a[:-1] + [a[0]] == a`
         ;   # End map
          A  # Are all the items truthy?
```

Comment: [11](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLFvMabP2wn4bmqx4/igbw7O0EiLCIiLCJbMSwgMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV0iXQ==)

Comment: @emanresuA that took me a bit to figure out how that worked lol

Comment: [10 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhUGoiLCLGmyIsIsOeS3bCr3bCpuKIqXbOoGEiLCIkXCJgIDw9IGBqIiwiWzEsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMV1cblszLCAzLCA3LCAzXVxuWzIsIDIsIDEsIDIsIDJdXG5bMiwgMSwgMiwgMiwgMl1cblsxLCAzLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDMsIDIsIDMsIDEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMV1cblsxLCAyXVxuWzEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMiwgMywgNF1cblszLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAzXVxuWzMsIDEsIDEsIDMsIDFdXG5bMSwgMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDJdIl0=) (link does test cases)

Comment: actually [8](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhUGoiLCLGmyIsInYt4bmYw57huIt2QWEiLCIkXCJgIDw9IGBqIiwiWzEsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMV1cblszLCAzLCA3LCAzXVxuWzIsIDIsIDEsIDIsIDJdXG5bMiwgMSwgMiwgMiwgMl1cblsxLCAzLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDMsIDIsIDMsIDEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMV1cblsxLCAyXVxuWzEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMiwgMywgNF1cblszLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAzXVxuWzMsIDEsIDEsIDMsIDFdXG5bMSwgMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDJdIl0=)

Comment: [alternative 8 not using inverted booleans](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhUGoiLCLGmyIsInY94bmYw57huIt2YUEiLCIkXCJgIDw9IGBqIiwiWzEsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMV1cblszLCAzLCA3LCAzXVxuWzIsIDIsIDEsIDIsIDJdXG5bMiwgMSwgMiwgMiwgMl1cblsxLCAzLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDMsIDIsIDMsIDEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMV1cblsxLCAyXVxuWzEsIDIsIDFdXG5bMSwgMiwgMywgNF1cblszLCAxLCAzLCAxLCAzXVxuWzMsIDEsIDEsIDMsIDFdXG5bMSwgMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAxLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDJdIl0=)

Comment: Sorry, can't edit old comments, but 7: `v=ṘÞḋṠA`

Answer (score 6):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 63 bytes

```
|k:&[u8]|(0..k.len()).all(|z|(z..k.len()).any(|q|k[q-z]==k[q]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNBboMwEDz0xiuWHCpbclCTVGqUCOXWTyArQqmREA5JbFO1CbykFw7tC_qa9jW1DRSKAurKspfdYVgvs2_vIpOq_IxS2IdxijBcHM4UROB_ZCqaLr82ebK6DbIlzdGd5yUeZxqFvZBzlJ9zdO7G0leUn_IkOE3P1Pf1STGuaL5vHtegzXGigwDEXo5sp9jTVjCZcUXgWT8eBIY4hcCB2pASGbM5tw0as5EZgRkl1-MDqQUBvR70fi07JzC37xpnAFBnBwAzy_-7j5S3sCSLhnDsIp3VQ1Lc-igKuRxt1lDFI5-vSrwfaGV722FAjRlt1jim7Xjze_7ZrN6VKbYu1QJvQkaKjLO9UV0lwE7SmJmESqHgQ4QM1gvlVvJ4x7Tg13_ARxGniqcumlxWmwIuxYRYdlJT9OChlEwoFzX8PvSGooMvrFfo6SmqcSrL6vwB)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>18</sup> 16 bytes

```
[:*/[:+.//.@|.e.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209KOttPX09fUcavRS9f5rcnGlJmfkKxgq2CqkAUlDNC6qgDEQmisYIwsZAaEhiEQVBAuhChoCNUMwhiXGQLXGYD2Y9kMhSAoiZwCVM0LjwvQiBIwVTJCFYNYbowuChVE14xCGegvsQQwpJMf@BwA)

*-2 thanks to ovs!*

Explanation slightly out of date (can't update right now), but idea is same.

Consider `3 3 7 3`:

- `-/~` Differences table:

  ```
  0 0 _4 0
  0 0 _4 0
  4 4  0 4
  0 0 _4 0
  ```
- `|.` Reversed:

  ```
  0 0 _4 0
  4 4  0 4
  0 0 _4 0
  0 0 _4 0
  ```
- `0&e./.` Is there a zero in each diagonal going this way `/`:

  ```
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ```
- `[:*/` Are they all 1:

  ```
  1
  ```

Comment: WTF that's incredible insight

Comment: `=/~` / monadic `e.` can save a couple bytes

Comment: @thejonymyster thanks, but note ovs had the same insight as well.

Comment: @ovs Very nice, thanks!

Comment: oh. i did not understand it ^_^; thank you i will have to study further

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Saved one byte thanks to [@Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

```
&=T&XdaA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X802RC0iJdHx//9oQx0FIDLWUTACk4ZghmEsAA)

**Explanation:**

```
&=        # input == input'
  T       # get all diagonals from...
   &Xd    # spdiags (i.e. rotate matrix 45 degrees)
      a   # `any` applied to columns
       A  # all
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Ooh, I didn't realize that the comparison operators did that! That's a very handy feature.

Comment: @LuisMendo I was confused about the truthy/falsy definitions since some answers explicitly collapse to a single value at the end and some don't. I may leave it because I like the extra 'a' in 'tadaa!'

Comment: Also, a single-value result looks neater

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
fqG&=&f-m
```

Outputs a truthy or falsy value, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19205/36398). Specifically, outputs

- a non-empty array containing only ones, which [is truthy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398), or
- an array containing at least a zero, which [is falsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P63QXc1WLU039///aEMdBSAy1lEwApOGYIZhLAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@t0F3NVi1NN/e/vXpJUWlJRqV6rXpaYk5xpXosl0tURcj/aEMdBcNYLjAFYRnrKACROZAEcox0FIzAMiAGhA/lQPiGYMVwEmGSMViJMUw5khVICCEBNQtJAKzZBOIehC1wPlQI2QkoQghXwnyA3QlguwE), including truthiness/falsihood test.

#### How it works

```
     % Implicit input
f    % Find: gives indices of non-zeros. Since the input contains non-zero
     % integers, this gives [1 2 ... n] where n is the input length
q    % Subtract 1, element-wise. Gives [0 1 ... n-1]
G    % Push input again
&=   % Matrix of pairwise equality comparisons
&f   % Two-output find: gives row and column indices of nonzero (i.e. true) entries
-    % Subtract, element-wise
m    % Ismember. This gives an array containing only true (or 1) if 0, 1,... n-1
     % are all contained in the above result (note that 0 will always be contained)
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
Πm▲∂↔´Ṫ=
```

Port of [*@ovs*' second Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249389/52210):

> Is there a zero on each diagonal of the subtraction table?

-2 bytes thanks to *@Steffan*, by using this instead:

> Is there a 1 on each diagonal of the equality table?

Outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yC3EfTNj3qaHrUNuXQloc7V9n@//8/2lDHUMdYxwiIDYGkYSwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
     ´    # Use the given input-argument twice,
      Ṫ   # to apply double-vectorized, creating a table
       =  # checking for each pair if they're equal
    ↔     # Reverse each inner row
   ∂      # Now pop and take all anti-diagonals of this matrix
          # (`∂↔` basically takes all diagonals of the matrix†)
 m        # Map over each diagonal-list:
  ▲       #  Maximum: check if any value in the diagonal-list is truthy
Π         # Product: check if all are truthy for each diagonal
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† Although Husk has an anti-diagonals builtin `∂`, it lacks a diagonals builtin. The reason for this is probably because the anti-diagonals can be computed on an infinite matrix, whereas this isn't the case for the diagonals, as [assumed by *@MartinEnder* here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153978/generalized-matrix-trace/153982#comment375944_153982).

Comment: I don't actually know husk, but here's [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yC3HOLH3U0PWqbcmjLw52rbP///x9tqGOoY6xjBMSGQNIwFgA). Returns 0 for falsy, and any other integer for truthy.

Comment: @Steffan Thanks. I've changed the sum to a max to get a consistent `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively. But smart to use an equality table instead of subtraction table! :) (And since this is only my 7th Husk answer, I honestly don't know Husk either ;p)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
.s€αPO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fr/hR05pzGwP8//@PNtZRMNRRgJKxAA) or [verify all testcases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/X@94kdNa85tDPD/r8MFkuEqz8jMSVUoSk1MUcjM40rJ51JQ0M8vKNGHGACl0My0UVABq81L/R9tqKNgGMsFpiAsYx0FIDIHkkCOkY6CEVgGxIDwoRwI3xCsGE4iTDIGKzGGKUeyAgkhJKBmIQmANZtA3IOwBc6HCiE7AUUI4UqYD7A7AWI3AA).

Returns zero if there are pairs at every distance, otherwise returns a non-zero number.

If this output format isn't allowed, it's +1 bytes for adding `_` in the end (and then it returns 1 if there are pairs at every distance and 0 otherwise). Alternatively, if you are willing to stretch the output format more you can remove the `O` in the end, and then it returns a list containing only zeros iff there are pairs at every distance

```
.s    All suffixes
€     Map each suffix to:
 α    The absolute difference of each value in the suffix from the matching value in the input
P     Product of each list - it's zero iff there's at least one pair of equal elements with distance X
O     Sum - since all values are positive, this is zero iff all values in the map are zero
```

Comment: Smart approach, and great use of 05AB1E's truncating unequal sized lists with that `.s€α`! (And [here is a test suite](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/X@94kdNa85tDPD/r8MFkuEqz8jMSVUoSk1MUcjM40rJ51JQ0M8vKNGHGACl0My0UVABq81L/R9tqKNgGMsFpiAsYx0FIDIHkkCOkY6CEVgGxIDwoRwI3xCsGE4iTDIGKzGGKUeyAgkhJKBmIQmANZtA3IOwBc6HCiE7AUUI4UqYD7A7AWI3AA) if you want one.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks! I added the test suite

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 91 bytes

```
;=l~1;W E++'=x'=l+1l'P'1;=aT;=wF;W<=w+1w l;=bF;=s~1;W<=s+1s-l w=b|b?E+'x'sE+'x'+s w=a&a bOa
```

Enter each number in the input list on their own line, with a trailing newline.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv3uXwFzU4sQaVpKO92JaNiTeO2dTBs5G7v17EpKBIKQxIYiFT4spxL717MX4AvUy@kHayTg4L5w7gP@gz7SmEXeIjkNQpd/Yz6NY/RL4E1nyXUUhRHiTwkP3BjJX6ssB7ynUcyb@8qZEvUhDRJv/jzuLok4na9YGMRJlLIkjHSKV8nMi604TCPGCc1gx1s8zLyExwvKuF7sz2nCZvrZR30wHA0HwxjWs97IWP9j8HEYjNr6MFi/wLh9hrMF559hN@JJGgVIET7ojNbrIPX9LBfmmIx08MrnCaLEsfgTZ7oCx3YhQhwhhNBL8aWnQojy3YpTB2zXKaixfB5Mkxk26YCNcJaE4LgXTHdalWUyHOj@v@@v78hgZOeh@p36KV/FCU08hhbiFnQHrxxrKzz2BKL4SCPwoWPTcymm0G9Tw8j9Y0SuD@jIKmXZ3kRnuLCHZYqvWZQGMuxRuEQBX@aMyFzupNMd63u8k0KsehNw/XTu8GgPrtwE3Jsw9DkN9gCr3axg1a8QjIj6FfHy0G2QLE4XQropRX1yaUKBa7mjipIdzhS/63O7PCl@N0FbbpQLKox/8YV5BYIiD6ymAePhJPdacePkRDEe@Jh/K6MghFchKEKyxZ@S63U23d@M8OD16f9G7TOzW1GenpyICxYyde1eE9pw5qbzReXMuHTmhczPDI8zP5nVrhzXtp6c0Ma1TVUcUnHHTWCWk3mRxjNdrGI7T5Xr/u9vP9z2313378kqKxLmrcuDZIMDz7k/oKd/fhqJz87pq08Qgs0ASKFgbHaITZ4AAZua8ZFHvYkHuDxEOU4ECsz1poGQo3gyqDGjipq5wXtQIoMfQ89FnWNxP6Xldp2gal3Wx78Fn4NwGSCvsgy1Gqa1xs2YSxdwGV8lut9Lr6FrbIcUAlqkC8WbpCo2ak5R11W4Up6vOWNQpXTgDGrwQfhpEz5P/YPwdhPueo@ql/WWuInGJZSi3tFkZgFvAqZIPQO/912SdkWDIEwQqII7Qc5X9CePQg1MDd2/qbtW@AN9Vh@IT/1Q0bcIl4f11eLX62Odnnfwdznfbn@H9/xpEQaCpDTh0iCUhFAbAz4Fvj1yBMbxCIz091SSc/Xe9tabiwaqQfya9n1oiId5r1Tvivj9oqTinPNCSKOElBVEtNuNHNAEWMfaoc4g5RXOPxNKFs7BTC6PWFoVjL95Sg2OWCujA83x2eAICjmEKj1Ha40wzHHx8G7UvsTD7pn5UtJKRAOY5ahEAg1iWMmHGGrlw50Aay3Rlth63dJa4guuXaqHVlH0wKq5FwCTXPQlDYFQPGBhKpa520MvVjQb72rp0v5mHpndDl6vOxs1qxgQDtUs4cS4ABQKt0uPANW6rIgvOIXeo1agZxhfjVoHGV@h1EuFxaK7winq3n0NWI9mJOJfUi/iujaJNWyuxIgstxxli8083/20iELGY4G6@a1/df/2tn9X9@YbqAGHWrPCkvyCYTKvxAwcpdPJm1ZmVVvh1WVPZp2xtvBZzhgu5mkxH4sfLszH7jkrZ2O3nI0nRFpklaYIZceTPXR650HvDqaIRtN0LgaOFyvX6GYIlKCJ8BI6qiMaqc3zwE5wptyxCITOTMfkGyMFLLGNsUKIIzT/HtA5J07@HVTHhG3PrvKAbllWhaoqS17FNaE98cJA14xKahUeB5UjpzxKDaKZSDMcK5dRdXFD26pNt84fnCWWF0v@mjAuZZNCFYr41IsTLl3EKwhtV/Sq8oG08ZbQtT6YhOYpDHkOJOoTZYn/FUEvQGxGI/gFM4sfBlOoSXZNEDoijqIRAlN1LvVqiySDF6juKHmA1dpTj1H5e8PeSQOtH6JHIRkKZeq7wlapwj2GWqlklQg4NqsQaO81U8fkoniSaZrpkDfpZMIji/p@yHQYwN1QBInqHWBEByZyEyjvwJMSO2D4Z5sZ4OoSMo7rXejCcke@5CyRWw8eJL42DDSMGWFW7HvwQuyY6LSe7MtKw3CmWvYht6zRuid@CL7@9PLVT69@/ufLVz@35WpEAzeci7Cp5681k5ILETLaCG0Nab1uCUiV6Hl4C6sctbuBAZelmbkkaxKF8ytgwFXowqBZvJ1wrzRXvU6LFbjXiZjZVCPfSCOpunSVLxWPS/mpbo/ldtWHms7tcVT7jzxUFESLP3mbVVzBHlcK5Fur@QBqIH@tkMJj1ZAymVT0vwS3LqrxrRHs0rI4ccM0sZYRNG4QmOc5NmkjZrdNQbXWQpo2HMrnYfnvD6Da5R4FBaJjlukPWNzbCR6LLnk0xmY1Pak2GUBWUU7qixMtt/CyEYbTLaR4IexCtreQokPvQp5tIeW7YAfyh22Z4W47P24h5fy9A3leISvSlEfEbFAdUc9c7D8z3Xfmcv8ZUfx3njmpzui0zPDGf2wui2O9Rg6unz1Ge852btrKsXzX3BUwosAaVUY8btdrUKk89JspTa3ipe6QSr/TEP5QCV@JPmo30tfGG4m3k8xvcxHQ/skF3Rkstu37v5VDMmi13abTeK6ZohEoP8taVqWjELJea1ozaneFAleqKA89o8ol7rbmClxmvRjwL6kB82VdERxsMKM2yXBFV65bx18ttfY1H/GAg@iMv9nE/6trP6Brw2iRpxbxja7fet/q2oTe22R5Yz@ck6XRXSLfJs6NTWKBPiex0Y1PfbQkztq5vDZaT61YfhoxrNETipxb@m0Mz1hP9Dz7W/eoe/Tj0Uv468Jn9@j/)

Also made a [test suite](https://tio.run/##lVh7V9s4Fv978imE2yEWNiaBnpktxnBaFnY5QwNb0uHsJmkjy0riqWOnfhA6ifvVu1fyS84D2pNDsKXffeq@lL/IA4lo6M7ifT9w2HfqkShCf/jueBJfhGEQIvYYM9@JkHhbpBngloQRq@9LNAXqfeLH7vR53F0cMjJd0MCP4jChcRCqBC/iiRsZUZCElFkkhR13dj9xYxbNCGVqvj8lMZ2oBx/VXn/Q7/UjWE@PB9ryRe9j3x/sqX1/@RLjvQOczhj7DLshi5PQRxLzXmuwXPqJ56UZM1unVgsvPBYjYtkGe2RUleDYzFlwEsuyyBl/OJYhlvRsRIkNuqsExBge88fxBOukRwc4jQMw3PXHG7VKU@EO1P3v7cWd1RuYmav@JF7CFlFMYpeiGT8F1cYL21hzjzkCLz6QEGxomeREsMnlm0TTMvuoJdZ7ZGAUvEx3pFKc60NTydY0THzh9jCYI5/Ns4hIHWYn4w3rW6wTTIxqE3CdZGqzcAuu2ATc2yDwGPG3AMvdNI@qa3BGSLwy8DLXrQRZlMw4d12w@uSQmECsZYZKQjYYk79XdJssyd/roDUzigUZxr54XL0cQZALWhOfsmCUWS2ZsbsrKQ/xmD0VXuDMSxfkLlmLnyLWq2zqXg5w783@/wZ7B3q7DHmyu8sPmPNUla7CpeHUSaaz0phhYcxLkZ8pHqZePKlM2al03d0ltWMbyzgk43bqwDQL5lkSTVS@is0sVS46f169v@m8u@h0rUWaJ8yVw/x4JQaeM79H9v/@NODfrf3Xn8AFqw4QTEHZ9KlocjkIoqnuH0HqjlzAZS7KcNxRoK479jkfyZJehRmUoZkpvAXFM/ghcB3U2uHnU2huVgkq12V1@MH/7AdzH7mlZqhZU605rPtcmIAL/0re/dHw6jvaukvBoXm6ELwaVPlGFVPEcaRYKeirmNGIVDpwCjX4Sfh@HT5NvCfhe3W44z7IVlZb/CRqh1CwekfiiQFx41OJ6wHYve2QlHPi@0GMQBScCbK/or9ZGCigauD8pOxK4K/kWXnAPvECSd4smD8tr2K/XO6o5KSFf8j4vb0fsJ49zgKfBymJmVAIxQHURp@NId4eGALlWAhKelsqyYl8blvrzWkNVQv8Kuw70BCfjnupepeB38lLKs5injOplZCigvB2u5IDCgerWHmqMwh@ufHPuJIGU1CTCRJDKZ3xk1Syc/ha4R1ojs86h4eQbRGp5yjNAYY5LurfDfbOcL99oB@KsOLegMiy5UACCXxYyYYYYmTDHQcrTd6W6HLZVJr8AVcmVUMrL3qg1dT1IZIc9CUJIKCYT4OELzPnGL1ckHS4qaUL/et5pLdbeLlsrdSsfEB4qmZxI4Y5IBe4Xno4qJJlhGzGCPQeuQI9E/HlqPVkxJco@VBhMe@uQEWcu68@PSapFbIviRsyVRlFCtYXfEQWW7a0RSeu53yahQFlEUddfuicd69uOndVb76EGvBUa5aiJDtgmMxLNj1b6nTipKVZ1ZTi6uxYZJ22NPBBFjGMz9N8PuYvDszHzgktZmOnmI1HltDIKFThwnZGW8LpnQu92x8jEo6TKR84Xi4crZ0iEIJG3EroqDZvpCbLHDvCqXTG3BEq1W2drYwUsERXxgrOziLZs0@mzLKzZxAdWXR9dhUEqmEYJaqsLFkVV7j02A18VdFKrqV7bFSMnIKUaJaiI0WzjYxH2cU1Za023dh/MRobbiTiV4dxKR3lolDIxm4UM2EiXoBr27xXFReklbuEqnRAJTRNYMizIVEfCY29rwh6AaITEsIbzCxe4I@hJplVgJCBZUsSwTFl55KPNk8yuIGqtpQHWK491RiV3TfMjWGgdAL0wDlDoUw8h@sqRDg7UCulrOIOx3rpAuVW0VVsneZXMkXRbettMhqx0CCeF1AVBnAn4E4iagsiogUTuQ4hb8OVEtug@GeTamDqHDKOqW3owmJH3OQMnlv3LiS@0vcVjKlFjchz4YbY0tF@NdkXlYbiVNbsfaZZrXWPvABsfXX4@tXr334/fP3bnlgNie8EU@42mf5C0Yl1yl1Gaq6tIM03TQ4pEz1zb66VLXc3UOCsUDPjZIzCYHoOEXAeODBo5ncnfFyoKx@nQXPcm5jPbLKSb4WSRF46z5byy6X4lreHYrvsQ3Xjthiq/EcQ5QXRYI/uahWXsDulAHHXql@AasjrEsktlhUpkklG/5PH1mk5vtWcXWgWxU6QxMY8hMYNDLM8xzqp@eymzqiSmnNT@n1xPSx@/oBQO9siIEe09CL9AYuPN4KHvEs2hlgvpydZJw2ClZeT6uB4y82trLlhfw3JbwibkHtrSN6hNyEP1pDiXrAB@es6z2Cznh/XkGL@3oA8KZFl0BQkfDYoSWSa0@004200Z9tpePHfSLNb0qikyPDaLzZnOdlxLQeXz5KRY3s9N02JLNvVNznMkmC1KsMvt8sliJQu@vWUJkZ@U7etUr5dY35fMl/wPmrW0tfEK4m3MZivMhbQ/q1TstFZdN32f0lEwmmV3rpdu67pvBFIr0UtK9ORM1kuFaXutbtcgCNEFETPiHIsZ11yCS6yng/4Z0SD@bKqCDbWqFappDm8K1et41tTrn31SzzgwDvD76Y1Qm@vb87/QOjFLOFXGLg/u764OJazwajxi2l539rmPbrQtKb12LQ8re01b5tt0yJd05pfmvcn1lxrz5FnWvalaUUcfWJFWjva99Dcspf22YXWfGxG4luLYI3sEmTfkEYDGKDb9zfvbrvoRUw@MwQlDSndMIknXxXQBgYsrhToB1ikWshF6jcEZbBh3v/76voCneSLGmojF2P0D/TiOghmiI8hyXiCGKETFAt@KGYwJlESscYv52@ur9EIvaAwRwgZlcX8F/mNRFuUvSRexFaVNW8@dG8/dFGzCc6F84x5LHuuz1bN@AkrRkLQT1qxSvR9aEB88XHE/J65udGGj/iCf0fw@R3@GofwaYvv8uGQo47yv5zkCFaPxH7JI/uIhcw14q3CcIJXjZLRUSPnd5Rt114KwYeykpWI/wM) cuz I'm bored lol

(Basically equivalent Python code: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLasMwELzrKxZfIhGnoLjQYqqrv8A31we7kYlAKMZykEPpt7trya9AC2I1sztoZtU@@uvNJO9tN44X2UBDB5YSAhoEaGmQIamQ5N1dEnCIskpbiV13VVoCdalwR87gA3RKAOpVAWARnziCWWpTYWfpyU1ir67h1sFQ2FIIrEdX4mByrKAyF6jRqe2U6WnFxlxEUVTwGHhJ/BVQEgOeN6xIzjGc/WQCgc8kcO7Fa91eSrwkWeQ7i93xAwxBSCEH@UWbQ0O/1Q87sAa3UKAM5C@21aqn0aeJWElCePzGbAk/p9g8gu1r2GTLt/K5tQ//1Nr2W3b/O7z3nsL/mz17yj7@Ag))

Comment: Congrats on figuring out semicolon! lol

Comment: The trailing newline is only necessary in the JS interpreter. If you use the others it will be fine

Comment: @Steffan Well I still don't really understand what it does but I found a reliable way to figure out where to put semicolons through a lot of trial and error. Basically, for every "indentation level" (like in python), put a semicolon in front of every statement except for the last statement in that indentation level. Seems to work so far.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you use it

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 56 bytes

```
\(x,n=seq(x),`?`=Map)any(\(i)all(\(j)x[j]-x[i+j]?n)?n-1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3LWI0KnTybItTCzUqNHUS7BNsfRMLNBPzKjViNDI1E3NygHSWZkV0VqxuRXSmdlasfZ6mfZ6uoSZE_y1G1zSNZA1DHQVDTU0uGBPBM9ZRACJzIAkVMNJRMAKrADEQYlABhJghWCOcRDXdGKzUGKYNzWokhCqJZDaaBNgwE4SbEbajiEGF0Z2IIYzwDcy3uJ0IcRckNBcsgNAA)

Outputs `FALSE` for truthy and `NA` for falsey.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 51 bytes

```
lambda a:all(map((a==[*zip(a)]).trace,a.argsort()))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDNTsMwDBaXHfoUPjqoVHRFAk3qW3DbdjAsgUj5k5chlVfZZRIa7wRPQ0natUhIluPP_mx_zvEzdPHVu9OHajfnQ1Q3D1-NIfu0I6AVGYOWAiK17fr6XQcksRVVZHqWJVXEL3vPEYUQQ-ujYm_BHWzoQNvQF4GYqSuUZzCgHfggHd6KiiXtjHZyj2JVgG4TDeUbGTRCFBBYu4gK9Tj79H21WNcl1NsiPTlqSujtvvc9WJawTJXfIOMBZFwn8sVPk5pEaUb6bMXMpsIwa5ZIzXdZz7TlgofUXMKf1KRyvOB_CXl3_o8f)

Takes a numpy array.

#### How?

Mostly straightforward.`zip` and `argsort` are used to avoid the direct `numpy` import. `zip` does roughly the same as transpose. The comparison with `a` creates a boolean table of pairwise incidence. The diagonals of this table are the distance groups. Taking the trace at different offsets returns a positive (hence truthy) value if there is a pair at that distance. `argsort` seems to be the cheapest way to create the offsets 0,...,n-1 not necessarily in order but we don't care.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <del>137</del> 136 bytes

```
(defn h[c](loop[n(count c)](if(not(contains?(set(map #(=(first %)(last %))(partition n 1 c)))true))false(if(> n 2)(recur(dec n))true))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn head-eq-tail [col]
  (loop [n  (count col)]
    (if (not (contains? (set (map #(= (first %) (last %)) (partition n 1 col))) true))
      false
      (if (> n 2)
        (recur (dec n))
        true))))
```

Comment: Here's a TIO link if you want it: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCgIxEAS/MiBCz1H34El9yLKHEBM2EidhMnl/NgqeGqqbap/Lu2sYA68QhfbVb8ilVFoFvnQx8rwhRUixCcRckvZEC4aPq3TCHTFpMzozsvslozq1ZKkICV2mgNm0B@bocgtf2WMWV4YG33Uee5L/hHmgapq/2GldaKEbLdukBw "Clojure – Try It Online"). Also, can't you remove the space after `loop`?

Comment: You're absolutely right. :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 43 bytes

```
f(x)=∑_{y=1}^{x.length}abs(x[y...]-x).min
```

Uses `0` for truthy, and any other positive integer for falsey.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/khmwikhogw)

Comment: You can do `(x[y...]-x)^2` instead of `abs(x[y...]-x)` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
0∊1⊥⍳∘≢↓⍤¯1∘.=⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBINHHV2Gj7qWPurd/KhjxqPORY/aJj/qXXJovSGQq2f7qHfF/5LU4hKgyupHfVOB1KPerepW6hppQFqzlgsipl5SVFqSUanOBVJ6aIWChqGCoSaYBNPGCsYK5grGQJaRghFQDEiC2WAWmG0IVAHBMH3GQBljsAq4SVAIEoHZm5aYU4xiLcQwmCaQESZgB0AtgLLBPLi1CB7UQWBHolsLMvs/AA)

Returns `0` if there are such pairs, and `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 78 bytes

```c
h;r;d;i;f(*t,n){for(r=1,d=n;--d;r&=h)for(h=i=0;i+d<n;)h|=t[i]==t[i+++d];*t=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZXbjtowEIbv9yksJKqcUDM5AfW6vaj6FIBWkDhL1MWgJFJpt7x6qRPbiTO7LTJxMt/v8cxPEvJF/rIXz/f7kda0oBUtHa8NhPtanmunZhAUTNDFoqD1B3Z0u@CRVSyklV88Cuoef7N2U@1Yd/R9v9hRr2U1vd0r0ZLTvhKOS14fiPx0gZY37RNsdoSRVwgI3OgYjsYwIrEicUDkWMqjDRMFo4BE/cruxObpwDVEPBu2jXtJ/Hb/pV1Z3KeITbqJcDVpwRpYuB6Ek1ogHONoBYCN5PbJhEaDRWMjE0FsC7RmIkiQD@9pUru/yBrYMcj@5YRq2dwQXi9vlFitDPTdoOdYz4meUz1nel7qeaXndWCsNCcmI5iUYHKCSQomK2RjbSoiVG1N9YufS0eJ3I/60tPXAbF5hHiEeIx4jHiCeIJ4iniKeIZ4hvgS8SXiK8RXiK8RXyMOITYoxIo3FmIPAZsI2EXANgL2EbCRgJ0EbCVgLwGbKQPWLcKvF563vPjP3S5H@O7QafKzaFqSH/e1J488/85rlW22vX6Lttf1V/lNZwGxr@OZXi3fx8TpKqlEwa9yWUj16aPpw9Q4NjJEKPH9Xu32ydR7enw0ZTr1ePaaHbUxEZrKJwTjsShdkCxG9Hu5g6b7XGopKp3ZvJkXssHqS9flp9lGTt1/ijvd8LAR1h4nfsovP52DlMp3oScscdlFBVrdyFK8wzTGZWz4BXETprgdWXwm84LMm62QhTXB8Cs1jHFT5O3hdv@Tly/75@a@@PEX)

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length (because poiters in C carry no length info).
Returns, through the input pointer, \$1\$ if the array has pairs at every distance or \$0\$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
āsŒʒ¬Qθ}€gêQ
```

I have the feeling this can be shorter. EDIT: And it defintely can: see [*@CommandMaster*'s 05AB1E answer, halve the size of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249436/52210).

I do like how this challenge can be done with a lot of different approaches, though.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SGPx0UmnJh1aE3huR@2jpjXph1cF/v8fbaijAETGOgpGYNIQzDCMBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/I43FRyedmnRoTeC5HbWPmtakH14V@F/nf3S0oY5hrA6IBNPGOsY65jrGQJaRjhFQDEiC2WAWmG0IVAHBMH3GQBljsAq4SVAIE4Hog/OAqk3AdkHNgrLBPLgNCB7UbrB70G0AmR0LAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length]
 s        # Swap so the input-list is at the top
  Œ       # Pop and get all its sublists
   ʒ      # Filter this list of sublists by:
    ¬Qθ   #  Check if the first and last items are the same:
    ¬     #   Get the first item (without popping the list)
     Q    #   Check for each item if it's equal to this first item
      θ   #   Then pop and push the last check
   }€     # After the filter: map over each remaining sublist:
     g    #  Pop and push the length
      ê   # Sorted-uniquify this list of lengths
       Q  # Check if it's equal to the [1,length] list we created initially
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
⊙θ⬤θ∨‹μκ⁻λ§θ⁻μκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMxr1KjUEfBMScHRPkXafikFhdr5OooZGvqKPhm5pUWa@QApUs881JSK0BKIGJgBRBg/f9/dLShjgIQGesoGIFJQzDDMDb2v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs an inverted Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` if there is a distance with no pair, nothing if there is a pair at every distance. Explanation:

```
 θ              Input array
⊙               Any distance satisfies
   θ            Input array
  ⬤             Every element satisfies
      μ         Current index
     ‹          Is less than
       κ        Current distance
    ∨           Logical Or
         λ      Current value
        ⁻       Does not equal
           θ    Input array
          §     Indexed by
             μ  Current index
            ⁻   Subtract
              κ Current distance
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 63 bytes

```
k=l.length
f(l)=0^{∏_{n=2}^k∑_{i=n}^k0^{(l[i-n+1]-l[i])^2}}
```

Returns `0` if truthy, `1` if falsey.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yjyiznpgr3)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h2uvimo1yo)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
*FsMqVRQ>LQU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8ut2LcwLCjQzicw9P//aGMdYx1DHeNYAA) -- [Truthy test suite](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfiv/F/Lrdi3MCwo0M4nMDRQwdb1//9oQx0Fw1guMAVhGesoAJE5kARyjHQUjMAyIAaED@VA@IZgxXASYZIxWIkxTDmSFUgILAEA) -- [Falsy test suite](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfiv/F/Lrdi3MCwo0M4nMDRQwdb1//9oQx0Fo1guMKWjYAhnGesomAA5QMoQzAGRcD5UCKIYixDECDgyRJZAQ0axAA)

Outputs zero for false, non-zero for true.

Pretty much a port of Command Master's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249436/65425) but double the length :/

Pyth has a prefix function (`._`) but no suffix function, so building the suffixes costs a few extra bytes with `>LQU`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org)

### 52 bytes

```
!X=0:length(X)-1⊆[I[1]-I[2] for I=findall(X.==X')]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBLUbtkqLSkoxK22iuaEMdBcNYHQgNZRrrKACROZAE8Yx0FIzAciAGVADKgwoYgtXDSSTjjMGKjGEakC1CQlCZWK60xJximKNgJiNpgxhlAnUiwlaEAFQMxVGoYgiXw7yFw1FQJ8RyLS0tSdO1uGmiGGFrYJWTmpdekqERoalr-KirLdoz2jBW1zPaKFYhLb9IwdM2LTMvJTEnRyNCz9Y2Ql0zFqrXAyQbYQsJdC4FBYfE4uLUohIFoJEgwVSu1LwULi6IInAYoKkBiYEVQcxbsABCAwA)

### 45 bytes - thanks to @MarcMush

```
!X=keys(X)⊆findall(X.==X').|>x->x[1]-x[2]+1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBLUbtkqLSkoxK22iuaEMdBcNYHQgNZRrrKACROZAE8Yx0FIzAciAGVADKgwoYgtXDSSTjjMGKjGEakC1CQlCZWK60xJximKNgJiNpgxhlAnUiwlaEAFQMxVGoYgiXw7yFw1FQJ8RyLS0tSdO1uKmrGGGbnVpZrBGh-airLS0zLyUxJ0cjQs_WNkJdU6_GrkLXriLaMFa3ItooVtsQqikwLb9IIcIWEtpcCkBQUJSZV5KTpxFha6cYocmVmpfCBRPS5OKCKAcHAw7VEIMXLIDQAA)

Comment: [45 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBLUbtkqLSkoxK22iuaEMdBcNYHQgNZRrrKACROZAE8Yx0FIzAciAGVADKgwoYgtXDSSTjjMGKjGEakC1CQlCZWK60xJximKNgJiNpgxhlAnUiwlaEAFQMxVGoYgiXw7yFw1FQJ8RyLS0tSdO1uKmrGGGbnVpZrBGh-airLS0zLyUxJ0cjQs_WNkJdU6_GrkLXriLaMFa3ItooVtsQqikwLb9IIcIWEtpcCkBQUJSZV5KTpxFha6cYocmVmpfCBRPS5OKCKAcHAw7VEIMXLIDQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 90 bytes

```
\(x,l=length,n=l(x),m=1:n)l(table(abs(outer(m,m,Vectorize(\(a,b)(x[a]==x[b])*(a-b))))))==n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVE7jsIwEBUtp7C2GqOhCAGxWmmuscUChY0cQJoElDhS2KvQhIJDsafZxHZIUmCN5vPm92zf7nn9N1nZvLTHqyDBp8LCHiIUkURvgxujaGTd6DZaoFi4XOsEIEQBiFz9Sw_Gxa4o7hqGiwbiMnKaKC7GxLrpg1Y_bhlo9pt7IGAjYmOsZ99d7Q0xR6EhRo_SJvPP588WKmRikx3sETNiqCSmFH1lksEqzQaULuBcWpNDiil-m70956dfA1tQqCVUG7UjqjZ6J2eg5lq6Q5SFDR-sLhe-gv8lFImcBsS9Tgv4yrr29h8)

Just checking that all distances are represented in the matrix of distances (where elements are zeroed for non-matches).

Answer (score 1):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 18 bytes

```
57 89 D7 49 AF 60 89 D6 F2 A7 61 E1 F7 0F 94 C0 5F C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPRbpswFH3GX3HLlMluaZRAt1Vh2Uuf97KnSWkUucYES2AQNhsp4tfHLk7IUCdVsizuOeeeeyRfRFXdH4UYBm4KoPDDpyTdeFVjMpCJIl5R/ho/Arxa4iVSgBQtqTeeEdwkxCn5RWYmWS0rLUEUlVOUFQrysqxeoSaekfYVeO7w84haWsJ8YDGRrZW1Bv/Jh8OBW1url8bKw4HSlBsreJ4zBiLjNaRUaQs6AFFqY2Esbjk6kA9Ki7xJJHw1NlHlMvtGiLHcKgHG1o2wYOVoZSR0ziJ2zXz3uI97MnFmt4ctdKQLA@jWAaz7PiBddCmm@gFrxPB8wdtBnxDCntCpxo85eoEm9PPZLnJENPN9vM6JnDyaWt/S83OlL5HDeeRwHnk9mT5cw80zRG/QC/F/5DnxL1M4O@v3I08p@5iMb1BwpSkjHfHSsgZ6flne2BI@Wthc380w4nlVjR0p9RfqWfsBroNd4jLYJWe4BFf2WX/nIlPjLpaJ3PgjN05q8XFXAZywTEroJjksVuFPdDttKW20UUctE7dutyxlu/bubs/iHn5nKpdAT3CDJu1TNB8IdKHg5YRRmcvVjiTud4NbvYpJPwx/RJrzoxnuiyjEC/@6LbbK/C8)

Following the `fastcall` calling convention, this takes the length of an array of 32-bit integers in ECX and its address in EDX, and returns 0 or 1 in AL.

In assembly:

```
f:  push edi      # Save EDI onto the stack.
    mov edi, edx  # Set EDI to the array address.
    dec ecx       # Subtract 1 from the length in ECX.
r:  scasd         # Advance EDI, also performing an unnecessary comparison.
    pusha         # Push all the registers onto the stack.
    mov esi, edx  # Set ESI to the array address.
                  # The distance between EDI and ESI increases each iteration.
    repne cmpsd   # Compare values at addresses EDI and ESI and advance both,
                  #  repeating ECX times but stopping if they are equal.
    popa          # Restore all registers' values from the stack.
    loopz r       # Subtract 1 from ECX, and jump back if it's nonzero
                  #  and the result of the last comparison is equal.
    setz al       # Set AL based on whether the result of the last comparison is equal.
    pop edi       # Restore the value of EDI from the stack.
    ret           # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 41 bytes

```
a->sum(i=1,#a,prod(j=i,#a,a[j]-a[j-i+1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVBLCsIwEMWbDLpJMFmkFeymvUgJMiCVFD-htgvP4qYg4pn0NCbp1KYLYZh58-b3kvvLYmN2B9s_KsifXVvJ7M1RFtfuxEyuxAqFbS57VufGYyxrLZ2TZq0058PAZ5GhtccbQ5AF2MacWweXPllCxZBzAWWpBCjtgI8EUwHOts77LBGQhJoHRFBGhAr9Px-tS0NTOg7EhyKLKuO-mAoLNiRsujURxM2kzLlJ7_iYP1KCBE0f2PdD_AI)

Returns `0` for truthy, other integers for falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
v=ṘÞḋṠA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwidj3huZjDnuG4i+G5oEEiLCIiLCJbMSwgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAxXVxuWzMsIDMsIDcsIDNdXG5bMiwgMiwgMSwgMiwgMl1cblsyLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAyXVxuWzEsIDMsIDEsIDMsIDEsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMywgMiwgMywgMSwgMiwgMV1cblsxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAyLCAxXVxuWzEsIDJdXG5bMSwgMiwgMV1cblsxLCAyLCAzLCA0XVxuWzMsIDEsIDMsIDEsIDNdXG5bMywgMSwgMSwgMywgMV1cblsxLCAzLCAxLCAxLCAzLCAxXVxuWzEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDFdXG5bMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMl0iXQ==)

Lyxal never posted my golf, so here goes

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 94 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJba4MwFH7vrzhIHxJQwXYw6FAYexiDPQy6PYkPpzbadN6WpIUh@e1OU227aRmc3L7vy7kkR8aYYVNu9ixW8IaCP1fv5boDoZ4BbFkCOfKCoEjlCh6FwO9wrQQv0oiu4KPgCnyjBDhiBopJ9YSSyRZ95VIRw8Bp79ngUfsvMgKXNrR2386/8YUNC6PvNiOqx0eUZ7yd58kElubicnAyneSVTWrGcadlJtDdqORLnlNUz94o7RZ7eZPh6f4tzRRiJHRmlvOPukkpGMY7qM8Y@EHvrWo7QmUFkda8Hlg3/zx1CrFCy4beIotqcAKY1wkZlFRbp5h61o2m67qE4GrNvsKXQkXUr48oYOOjm7EiVbsH4oEqYUPdHKua@wHhV@e9HyDZOx51uoVT7Vai3B5ipV15yHWjmx8)

```scala
def f(a:Seq[Int])={var b=a.length;(1 to b).map{i=>(i to b).map{j=>a(j-1)-a(j-i)}.product}.sum}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLasMwELz7KxaTgwSOwHGhEEig9FAKPRTSnkwOW8d25PqFpBSK8be7svxqaoeCLC0zo91ZeWWAKTZN8ZGEgYJXFPypfCsOLQqVBXAKI8iQ5wRFLLfwIAR@@wcleB4f6Rbec65gZ5QAX5iCCqV6RBlKjb5wqYhhoItdB1zq/EVmoOeAXvd6v8Y3DmyMvg1mVI/PKNdkG/dFA5656A1Jlk3@Wouaed1lmSl0N2t58rlE9eyN1m6x05sMT/dva6YRI6GWOcY/yqJChBicoRox2O37bKWeCJXmRNqramBZ9tlNCrF924F@HW1aw3oPqyoig5LWdlezttqvn7uI4NbY9J9z1U6bPsZhIy6oApClYR6rM2UZltoYnxwRviRIJgEAkgTW@kn01oWc9lzNSlGcLoHqXDF5yYyz2mqaHw)

```scala
object PariGpToScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testCases = List(
      List(1, 1),
      List(1, 1, 1),
      List(3, 3, 7, 3),
      List(2, 2, 1, 2, 2),
      List(2, 1, 2, 2, 2),
      List(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1),
      List(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
      List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
      List(1, 2),
      List(1, 2, 1),
      List(1, 2, 3, 4),
      List(3, 1, 3, 1, 3),
      List(3, 1, 1, 3, 1),
      List(1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1),
      List(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
      List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
    )

    testCases.foreach { testCase =>
      println(s"${testCase.mkString("[", ", ", "]")} -> ${f(testCase)}")
    }
  }

  def f(a: List[Int]): Int = {
    (1 to a.length).map { i =>
      (i to a.length).map { j =>
        a(j - 1) - a(j - i)
      }.product
    }.sum
  }
}
```